# How two avoid cmake repeat build for two similar libraries

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I am planning to add unittests to a project whose product is a shared library.
The original library limits the public symbols:

```
function(export_signatures TARGET_NAME)
    target_link_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
    -Wl,--version-script=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/exports.linux.list -Wl,--no-undefined)
endfunction()
```

This will give undefined reference if I use internal symbols in my test. So I figured I could build a version of the library to avoid repeating build steps.
So I created a loop:

```
set(MY_TARGETS mylib)
if (ENABLE_TEST_BUILD)
    list(APPEND MY_TARGETS mylib-test)
endif()

foreach(TARGET_NAME ${MY_TARGETS})
    add_library(${TARGET_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})
    if (TARGET_NAME STREQUAL "mylib") #skip test library
        export_signatures(${TARGET_NAME})
    endif()
    install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
endforeach()
```

And now I can see that sources are visited *twice*, and my build time is increased by 50%.

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object path/CMakeFiles/mylib-test.dir/util.cpp.o
[ 100%] Building CXX object path/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/util.cpp.o
```

Is there a way to avoid that?
More generic question: Is this a sane design anyway? What'd you suggest?

Comment: It seems sane and almost unavoidable; you seem to need two different object files (.o), one with the symbols and one without.  One other avenue may be to only build the version with symbols, then strip the symbols from the library with an external tool (like 'strip') to obtain the other version.

Comment: The way I usually solve this is to split the shared library into an (internal) static library where all symbols have hidden visibility, and a small shared wrapper library that defines only exported functions which simply forward to the functions in the static library. That way the the tests can link the static library and have access to all symbols, and the shared library has the same interface as before without compiling all library code twice.

Comment: Just create static library which holds your code. Then add two dynamic library targets: one for deployment (which exports only required symbols), the other for testing (which exports everything). Both of those dynamic libraries will link this static library.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try the suggestions and come back, starting with static->2Xshared suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I solved the issue like this:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
# Remove shared library specific file(s)
list(REMOVE_ITEM ${SOURCES} dllmain.cpp)

# Build only Object files
add_library(objects OBJECT ${SOURCES})

add_library(target1 SHARED dllmain.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objects>)
# target1 specific setting here ...

add_library(target2 SHARED dllmain.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objects>)
# target2 specific setting here ...
```